# suse linux ftp maximum number of files

Tags: linux, ftp

How do I change the maximum number of files allowed to be listed/transferred... on suse linux? both client and server are suse linux machines.

Comment: What ftp service do you use vsftpd , pureftpd proftp ?

Comment: Which SUSE are you using, SLES or OpenSUSE?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running into limitations with shell globing. Things like expanding a `*` to a set of files is limited in bash.

The thing to do is change the way you produce your file sets to a more appropriate method. The right tool for the job will not have limitations in this area. Using `rsync` is the first thing that comes to mind, or using one tool to generate a list and then iterating over it is another depending on your scenario. If you want more specific advice you will have to explain your situation more fully.